# How To Capture Unit Testing Metrics

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, junit, perforce

I'm not sure how to capture the testing result data related to unit tests each time a unit test is run. I use Bamboo as a continuous integration server. It works great, basically makes a build of your project every time you submit code, and send you an email if the build failed / you screwed up somewhere. I would like to begin having Bamboo running full unit tests as well as builds. I would also like to begin gathering data about said unit tests.

My question is, I know in a lot of dif programs you can track the number of lines of code changed, and the total lines of code period in the entire program. I also know that with unit testing, it gives you data such as the number of passes / failures. What I would like to do is automatically gather this data, among other data such as defect density, etc.